# Copy Constructor and memory allocation

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Why is the memory address of message.pmessage the same before and after the constructor is called? Shouldn't the memory address of message.pmessage be different if it was allocated with new? I'm confused.

**Overloaded Operator function**

```
CMessage operator+(const CMessage& aMess) const
    {
      cout << "Add operator function called." << endl;
      size_t len = strlen(pmessage) + strlen(aMess.pmessage) + 1;
      CMessage message;

      //
      cout << &message.pmessage << endl;
      cout << message.pmessage << endl;
      message.pmessage = new char[len];
      message.test = new char[len];
      cout << &message.pmessage << endl;
      //

      strcpy_s(message.pmessage, len, pmessage);
      strcat_s(message.pmessage, len, aMess.pmessage);
      return message;
    }
```

**Constructor**

```
CMessage(const char* text = "Default message")
{
  cout << "Constructor called." << endl;
  pmessage = new char[strlen(text) + 1];         // Allocate space for text
  strcpy_s(pmessage, strlen(text)+1, text);      // Copy text to new memory
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is there the constructor called?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow When I declare the object message inside the overloaded operator function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are printing the address of a pointer inside one object, of course it is always going to be the same. To print out of the address that pointer is pointing to, you can try this

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(message.pmessage) << endl;
```

you need `static_cast<void*>` because you want to avoid printing the c string.